# apostrophe problems with twitter share url

Tags: jquery, string, razor, twitter

So I realized that apostrophes gives `"&#39"`,

I have a JS that does following:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#share_buttont@(number)').click(function () {
            var loc = $(this).attr('href');
            window.open('http://twitter.com/share?url=' + loc + '&text=' + "@item.Title. News via www.test.com" + '&', 'twitterwindow', 'height=450, width=550, top=' + ($(window).height() / 2 - 225) + ', left=' + $(window).width() / 2 + ', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
        });
    });
```

If `@item.Title` contains `" 'Flying' boat to smash record? "`, text with a apostrophes  ruins the text inside the twitter share box. apostrophes turns into `&#39`.

Is there any good ways to fix this, or do I need to remove all apostrophes on the text? before the JS script triggers?